Why constraining a generic type to Record<string, any> prevents the error ``is not assignable to type string|number|symbol``?
I am using mapped generic types to create new object types based on original type.
type ToyBase={
    name:string;
    description:string;
    minimumAge:number;
}

type BoardGame=ToyBase &{
    kind:"boardgame";
    players:number;
}

type Puzzle=ToyBase & {
    kind:"puzzlee";
    pieces:number;
}

type Toy= BoardGame | Puzzle;

type Group<Collection, Selector extends keyof Collection>={
    [x in Collection[Selector]]:Collection[];
}

For the Group implementation typesscript throws an error as
Type 'Collection[Selector]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'Collection[keyof Collection]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
    Type 'Collection[string] | Collection[number] | Collection[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
      Type 'Collection[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'

What I understand from this error is that lets say I have a type person
type Person= {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: { city: string; state: string };
}

const groupedPeople = Group<Person, "address">;

The above implementation is wrong and typescript error is also warning for such an implementation, where Collection[string] might not be a string and in this case it is an object.
But if I constrain Collection with Record<string,any> typescript stops throwing the error.
Here is the implementation:
type Group<Collection extends Record<string, any>, Selector extends keyof Collection>={
    [x in Collection[Selector]]:Collection[];
}


I found that Record is a helper type whose implementation is
type Record<K extends string|number|symbol, T>= {[P in K]: T }

If we are passing T type as any, then how is the new implementation of Group type better than the former implementation? And why typescript is not throwing error now?
Because in this case also I could pass Person and it will be a wrong implementation.
Please let me know if any part of the question is unclear.

I don't know if there's a great source document for what's happening here. Record<string, any> aka {[k: string]: any} is intentionally made looser than other index signature types (as per this comment) and so it allows things people don't expect, as per ms/TS#49302. Does that address the question sufficiently? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
